# $\mathrm{d}\mu(x) = \mathrm{d}\lambda(x)/x$, $\lambda$ is Lebesgue. Is $L^{\infty}([0,1],\lambda) = L^{\infty}([0,1],\mu)$?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, lp-spaces, haar-measure

**Definitions:**

Let $\lambda$ be the Lebesgue measure on $G$. Define Haar measure $\mu$ on $G$ by $\mathrm{d}\mu(x) := \frac{1}{x}\mathrm{d}\lambda(x)$.

$G$ is multiplicative group, $G=(R_+,⋅)$. Since my functions are $L^1(\mathbb{R})$, they are well behaved on $[1,\infty)$, so I am interested in $[0,1]$, where the $1/x$ in $\mu$ might blow up the finiteness of measure. Here, suppose $G = [0,1]$.

---

**Motivation:**

It is simple to show $\|f\|_{L^p(G,\lambda)} \leq \| f \|_{L^p(G,\mu)}$. Thus,

\begin{equation}
L^p(G,\mu) \subset L^p(G,\lambda).
\end{equation}

I am trying to understand the difference between $L^{\infty}(G,\lambda)$ versus $L^{\infty}(G,\mu)$.

---

**Question 1:** I like to take the limit $p \to \infty$ to obtain $L^{\infty}(G,\mu) \subset L^{\infty}(G,\lambda)$. Is there any issue with this? I know that

\begin{equation}
\lambda(G) < \infty \quad \Rightarrow \quad \lim_{p\to \infty} \| f \|_{L^p(G,\lambda)} = \| f \|_{L^{\infty}(G,\lambda)}
\end{equation}

On the other hand, $\mu(G) = \infty$, so I am not sure taking the limit $p \to \infty$ is still valid. However, $\mu$ is $\sigma$-finite. Can I still conclude the following?

\begin{equation}
\lim_{p\to \infty} \| f \|_{L^p(G,\mu)} = \| f \|_{L^{\infty}(G,\mu)}
\end{equation}

---

**Question 2:** Do all *bounded* functions on $G$ are also in $L^{\infty}(G,\mu)$? I guess yes, because, by definition

\begin{equation}
L^{\infty}(G,\mu) = \inf_a \{ \mu(\{x: f(x) > a\}) = 0 \}
\end{equation}
When $|f| < M < \infty$ for all $x \in G$, then $\{x: f(x) > M\} = \emptyset$, and $\mu(\emptyset) = 0$ thus $\| f \|_{L^{\infty}(G,\mu)} \leq M$.

---

**Question 3:** Do all *essentially bounded* (with respect to $\lambda$) functions on $G$ are in $L^{\infty}(G,\mu)$? In effect, this would mean

\begin{equation}
L^{\infty}(G,\lambda) \subset L^{\infty}(G,\mu),
\end{equation}
and combined with $L^{\infty}(G,\mu) \subset L^{\infty}(G,\lambda)$ (in question 1), yields $L^{\infty}(G,\lambda) = L^{\infty}(G,\mu)$. Is this true?

To show question 3, I should know if zero measure by $\lambda$ implies zero measure by $\mu$. In other words, does

\begin{equation}
\mu \ll \lambda
\end{equation}
hold ($\mu$ is absolutely continuous)?

---

I am learning measure theory very recently, so please elaborate your answers if possible. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Q 1: Yes, $\|f\|_p \to \|f\|_{\infty}$ as $ p \to \infty$ even for infinite measures.

For Q 2: Yes, bounded functions belong to $L^{\infty}(\mu)$ even for infinite measures $\mu$.

For Q 3: $\mu(E)=\int_E \frac 1 x d\lambda(x)=0$ whenever  $\lambda (E)=0$ so $\mu << \lambda$ so $L^{\infty}(\lambda) \subset L^{\infty}(\mu)$.

Comment: Thanks Kavi. On Q3 I have few questions.What if $E_n = (\frac{1}{2n},\frac{1}{n})$. Then $\lambda(E_n) \to 0$ but $\mu(E_n) = \ln 2$. Does the continuity definition still hold? i.e., $\forall \epsilon > 0$, $\exists \delta > 0$, $\lambda(E) < \delta$ implies $\mu(E) < \epsilon$.


Radon-Nikodym (RN) derivative $f = \frac{d\mu}{d\lambda} = \frac{1}{x} > 0$ but is not $\lambda$-measurable, which is required by RN theorem for $\mu \ll \lambda$.

We have $\lambda \ll \mu$. With above it implies $\lambda \sim \mu$. But one is finite and the other is infinite. Can these two be equivalent?

Comment: @Sia The integral of any non-negative measurable function over a set of measure $0$ is $0$, so what I have claimed is true.  You can certainly have an infinite measure which is absolutely continuous w.r.t. a finite measure.

Comment: I see now. I found the above $\epsilon$-$\delta$ argument in my comment work for when $\mu$ is finite (Folland Thm 3.5) but not in general. Overall, here $\lambda \sim \mu$ holds even for  $G = \mathbb{R}_+$, which itself yields the identification $L^{\infty}(G,\lambda) = L^{\infty}(G,\mu)$. I conclude the essential sup only depend on measure equivalency. Please correct me if I am wrong, and thank you again Kavi.

Comment: @Sia You are right. We only need equivalence of null sets.